# NMaximize does not globally maximize. What is the alternative for global solution?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
g1[a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_] :=Piecewise[{{(a0*a1*a2)/(a1*a2*(-b0 + b1)+ a0*(a1*(1 + a2 + a2*b0 - b2) + a2*(-b1 + b2))), 0 <= (a0*a1*a2)/(a0*a1 + a0*a1*a2 - a1*a2*b0 + a0*a1*a2*b0 - a0*a2*b1 + a1*a2*b1 - a0*a1*b2 + a0*a2*b2) <= a2}}, 1]

g2[a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_] :=Piecewise[{{((a0*b1 - a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1))^2 - 2*a0*(a1*(b0 - b1) + a0*(a1^2 - a1*b0 + b1))*b2 + a0^2*(1 + a1^2)*b2^2)/(2*(a1*(-b0 + b1) + a0*(a1*(-1 + b0) - b1 + b2))*(a1*(-b0 + b1) + a0*(a1 + a1*b0 - b1 + b2))), a2 <= (a0*a1*(-1 + b2)*(a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) + a0*(-b1 + b2)))/((a1*(-b0 + b1) + a0*(a1*(-1 + b0) - b1 + b2))*
  (a1*(-b0 + b1) + a0*(a1 + a1*b0 - b1 + b2))) <= a1}}, 1]

g3[a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_] :=Piecewise[{{(a0*a1*(2*a1*(-b0 + b1)*b2 - a0*(a1 + 2*(-(a1*b0) + b1)*b2 + (-2 + a1)*b2^2)))/(2*(a1*(-b0 + b1) + a0*(a1*(-1 + b0) - b1 + b2))*(a1*(-b0 + b1) + a0*(a1 + a1*b0 - b1 + b2))), a2 <= (a0*a1*(-(a0*a1) + b2*(a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) + a0*(-b1 + b2))))/
 (-(a0^2*a1^2) + (a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) + a0*(-b1 + b2))^2) <= a1}}, 1]

g4[a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_] :=Piecewise[{{((-1 + a0)^2*b0^2 + 2*(-1 + a0)*b0*b1 + b1*(a0^2*(-2 + b1) + b1))/(2*(a0*(-1 + b0) - b0 + b1)*(a0 - b0 + a0*b0 + b1)), a1 <= (a0*(-b0 + a0*b0 + b1 + b0*b1 - a0*b0*b1 - b1^2))/(a0^2 - b0^2 + 2*a0*b0^2 - a0^2*b0^2 + 2*b0*b1 - 2*a0*b0*b1 - b1^2) <= a0}}, 1]

g5[a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_] :=Piecewise[{{(a0*(-a0 + 2*(-1 + a0)*b0*b1 - (-2 + a0)*b1^2))/(2*(a0*(-1 + b0) - b0 + b1)*(a0 - b0 + a0*b0 + b1)), a1 <= (a0*(-a0 - b0*b1 + a0*b0*b1 + b1^2))/(-a0^2 + b0^2 - 2*a0*b0^2 + a0^2*b0^2 - 2*b0*b1 + 2*a0*b0*b1 + b1^2) <= a0}}, 1]

g6[a0_, b0_] :=Piecewise[{{b0/(1 + b0), a0 <= b0/(1 + b0) <= 1}}, 1]

fmymin[a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_] :=Min[1/2, (a0^2 - 2*(-1 + a0)*b0 - (-1 + a0)^2*b0^2)/2, ((2 - a0)*a0 + (-1 + a0)^2*b0^2)/2, (a1^2 + 2*b1 - (2*a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1))/a0 - (b1 - (a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1))/a0)^2)/2, (2*a1 - a1^2 + (b1 - (a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1))/a0)^2)/2, (a2^2 + 2*b2 - (2*a2*(a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) + a0*(-b1 + b2)))/(a0*a1) - (b2 - (a2*(a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) + a0*(-b1 + b2)))/(a0*a1))^2)/2, (2*a2 - a2^2 + (b2 - (a2*(a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) + a0*(-b1 + b2)))/(a0*a1))^2)/2, g1[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], g2[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], g3[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], g4[a0, b0, a1, b1], g5[a0, b0, a1, b1], g6[a0, b0]]

fmyminorg[a0_, b0_, a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_] :=Min[(a0^2 + 2*(1 - a0)*b0 - (1 - a0)^2*b0^2)/2, (2*a0 - a0^2 + (1 - a0)^2*b0^2)/2, (a1*(a0^2*a1 - 2*(-1 + a0)*a0*b0 - (-1 + a0)^2*a1*b0^2) + 2*(a0 - a1)*(a0 + (-1 + a0)*a1*b0)*b1 - (a0 - a1)^2*b1^2)/(2*a0^2), (a1*(-(a0^2*(-2 + a1)) + (-1 + a0)^2*a1*b0^2) + 2*(-1 + a0)*a1*(-a0 + a1)*b0*b1 + (a0 - a1)^2*b1^2)/(2*a0^2), (a0 + a1 - a0*a1 + ((-1 + a0)*b0*(-(a0*b1) + a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1)))/a0)/2, (a0^2*(a1 - a1*b0^2 + b0*(-1 + b1)) - a1*(-1 + b0)*(b0 - b1) + a0*(2*a1*b0^2 + b1 - b0*(-1 + a1 + b1 + a1*b1)))/(2*a0), (a0 + a2 - a0*a2 + ((-1 + a0)*b0*(a1*a2*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) - a0*a1*b2 + a0*a2*(-b1 + b2)))/(a0*a1))/2, (a1 + a2 - a1*a2 + ((-(a0*b1) + a1*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1))*(a1*a2*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) - a0*a1*b2 + a0*a2*(-b1 + b2)))/(a0^2*a1))/2, (2 + a2^2 + 2*a2*((b0 - a0*b0 - b1)/a0 + (b1 - b2)/a1 + (-1 + b2)/a2) - (a1*a2*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) - a0*a1*b2 + a0*a2*(-b1 + b2))^2/(a0^2*a1^2))/2, (2*a2 - a2^2 + (a1*a2*((-1 + a0)*b0 + b1) - a0*a1*b2 + a0*a2*(-b1 + b2))^2/(a0^2*a1^2))/2, (-(a1^2*a2*(b0 - b1)^2) + a0*a1*(b0 - b1)*(a1 + a2 + 2*a1*a2*b0 - 2*a2*b1 - a1*b2 + a2*b2) + a0^2*(a1^2*(a2 - a2*b0^2 + b0*(-1 + b2)) - a2*(-1 + b1)*(b1 - b2) + a1*(b1 + a2*b0*(-1 + 2*b1 - b2) + b2 - b1*b2)))/(2*a0^2*a1), (-(a1*a2*(-1 + b0)*(b0 - b1)) + a0^2*(a1*(a2 - a2*b0^2 + b0*(-1 + b2)) + a2*b0*(b1 - b2)) + a0*(-(a2*(-1 + b0)*(b1 - b2)) + a1*(2*a2*b0^2 + b2 - b0*(-1 + a2 + a2*b1 + b2))))/(2*a0*a1)]

max = NMaximize[{fmymin[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] - fmyminorg[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], {a1 <= a0 <= 1, 0 <= b0 <= 1, a2 <= a1 <= a0, b0 <= b1 <= b2, 0 <= a2 <= 1, b1 <= b2 <= 1}}, {a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2}]
(* {0.0218682, {a0 -> 0.612102, b0 -> 0.0022207, a1 -> 0.144964, 
                b1 -> 0.211932, a2 -> 0.144964, b2 -> 0.545072}} *)

max = NMaximize[{fmymin[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] - fmyminorg[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], {0 <= a0 <= 1, 0 <= b0 <= 1, a2 <= a1 <= a0, b0 <= b1 <= b2, 0 <= a2 <= a1, b1 <= b2 <= 1}}, {a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2}]
(* {0.0231773, {a0 -> 0.705064, b0 -> 0., a1 -> 0.20014, b1 -> 0.306156, 
                a2 -> 0.00654739, b2 -> 0.842462}} *)

max = NMaximize[{fmymin[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] - fmyminorg[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], {0 <= a0 <= 1, 0 <= b0 <= b1, a2 <= a1 <= a0, b0 <= b1 <= b2, 0 <= a2 <= a1, 0 <= b2 <= 1}}, {a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2}]
(* {0.0232671, {a0 -> 0.691563, b0 -> 0., a1 -> 0.192949, b1 -> 0.298011,
                a2 -> 0.144842, b2 -> 0.95349}} *)

max = NMaximize[{fmymin[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] - fmyminorg[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], {a1 <= a0 <= 1, 0 <= b0 <= b1, a2 <= a1 <= a0, b0 <= b1 <= b2, 0 <= a2 <= 1, 0 <= b2 <= 1}}, {a0,b0, a1, b1, a2, b2}]
(* {0.0216001, {a0 -> 0.620419, b0 -> 0.0905576, a1 -> 0.212008, 
                b1 -> 0.290074, a2 -> 5.25103*10^-9, b2 -> 0.679186}} *)
```

Just as a side note, all $4$ (same) optimization problems above have exactly the same constraints but written slightly differently. Namely we have:

$$1\geq a_0\geq a_1\geq a_2\geq 0$$
$$1\geq b_2\geq b_1\geq b_0\geq 0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a satisfactory answer but maybe a start using a brute force approach.

First the online help states:

- `NMaximize` always attempts to find a global maximum of f subject to 
  the constraints given.
- If f and cons are linear, `NMaximize` can always find global maxima,
  over both real and integer values.
- Otherwise, `NMaximize` may sometimes find only a local maximum.

Note the word "attempts" which applies in your case.  So the brute force approach would be to use `FindMaximum` which only purports to find a local maximum.  One could use random starting values for the parameters (subject to the constraints) or select starting values from a fine enough grid (again subject to the constraints).

Here's the random starting value approach:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
Do[
 startingValues = 
  Flatten[{Sort[RandomReal[1, 3]], Sort[RandomReal[1, 3]]}];
 parms = {a2, a1, a0, b0, b1, b2};
 init = Transpose[{parms, startingValues}];
 max = FindMaximum[{fmymin[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] - 
     fmyminorg[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], {0 < a2 <= a1 <= a0 < 1, 
     0 < b0 <= b1 <= b2 < 1}}, init];
 If[i == 1, best = max, If[max[[1]] > best[[1]], best = max]],
 {i, 1000}]
best
(* {0.0226371, {a2 -> 1.58994*10^-17, a1 -> 0.266554, a0 -> 0.941873,
                b0 -> 0.260884, b1 -> 0.333375, b2 -> 0.767125}} *)
```

Here's a grid search approach:

```
n = 6;
max = ConstantArray[0, (1/6 (-1 + n) n (1 + n))^2];
k = 0;
Do[Do[Do[Do[Do[Do[
      k = k + 1;
      startingValues = {i2/n, i1/n, i0/n, j0/n, j1/n, j2/n};
      parms = {a2, a1, a0, b0, b1, b2};
      init = Transpose[{parms, startingValues}];
      max[[k]] = 
       FindMaximum[{fmymin[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] - 
          fmyminorg[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2], {0 < a2 <= a1 <= a0 < 1, 
          0 < b0 <= b1 <= b2 < 1}}, init];
      If[max[[k, 1]] > best[[1]], best = max[[k]]],
      {i2, 1, i1}], {i1, 1, i0}], {i0, 1, n - 1}], {j0, 1, j1}], {j1, 1, j2}], {j2, 1, n - 1}]
best
(* {0.0231124, {a2 -> 3.33598*10^-9, a1 -> 0.194261, a0 -> 0.827781,
                b0 -> 0.213226, b1 -> 0.218863, b2 -> 0.672657}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Brute force search is just okay. The point is that I am still not able to get the global optimum. I know that the answer is at least $0.0233$ and I obtained with Nmaximize $0.0232$ with {a0 -> 0.699024, b0 -> 0.00182182, a1 -> 0.194679, b1 -> 0.296958, 
  a2 -> 0.17766, b2 -> 0.92299}}

Comment: btw. I am running the second grid search method on my computer and it has been some hours already. How much more should I wait?

Comment: It took a little over 5 minutes with `n = 6` on my laptop.

Comment: still running on my computer. I think there should be something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more direct approach:  playing with `Method`.

```
NMaximize[{fmymin[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2] - fmyminorg[a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2],
  {0 < a2 <= a1 <= a0 < 1, 0 <= b0 <= b1 <= b2 < 1}}, {a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2},
 Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 500}]
(* {0.0233256, {a0 -> 0.90198, b0 -> 0., a1 -> 0.711278,
                b1 -> 3.28891*10^-6, a2 -> 0.200922, b2 -> 0.307387}} *)
```

Comment: This is also currently what I am running on my machine with some different seeds. I am still unsure whether I have the global optimum. I would prefer to use your other answer but It doesnt work. Could you please add a pure brute force search method so that I can accept the answer? I mean all parameters can take values from $\{0.01,0.02,...,1\}$. It is like 6 times for loop as in your answer with DODODO.. but no need for Findmaximum, It must just calculate the difference of those two functions and keep the best result at each iteration. Thanks for the answers once again.